# SOLR query with DISMAX giving empty result with code and working fine with solr admin

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solrconfig, solr7, solrclient

I'm trying to query certain fields using "DISMAX Query Parser" , so the query is like below,

```
https://localhost:8983/solr/OOOOO/select?bq=country:PL^100.0&dType=dismax&defType=dismax&df=dismax&q=25392907{!boost}(%2B{!lucene+v%3D$yq})&qf=xxx_text
```

which is working fine in Solr Admin console but when trying to write logic via code and execute it the result is empty.

The query framed in code level,

```
 yq=(25392907)&q={!boost}(%2B{!lucene+v%3D$yq})&bq=country:PL^100.0&defType=dismax&dType=dismax&df=dismax&qf=xxx_text
```

Need help on this query framing to understand more in solr.

Thanks !!

Comment: .. but there's a completely different query in your other example? (i.e. the boost/lucene/etc. in `q`). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatsLindh  : updated the query. The first one when we hit in browser url itself we are getting the solr response, but when framed via code logic, the query framed from Hybris is second query. Both the query parameters are same, but we are getting empty resultset.

Answer (score 0):

After solr 7.2 it doesn't support Local param {! for edismax.
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/major-changes-in-solr-8.html